# extracting value from double dictionary python

Tags: python

This might be a very stupid question, but i want to know how i can extract the `RFC822.SIZE` value from the double dictionary of the form:

```
{1: {'RFC822.SIZE': 2515, 'SEQ': 1}, 
2: {'RFC822.SIZE': 2942, 'SEQ': 2}, ....
```

Comment: By what criteria do you want to extract that key, and not (say) `'SEQ'`?

Comment: I am trying to extract only the Size, i dont really care about the `SEQ`. I am separating the key and the value like this: `for item in sizeList:
    print item, sizeList[item]` i want to be able to access `sizeList[item]` and extract the size. But `sizeList[item][0]` doesnt seem to work, neither does `sizeList[item['RFC822.SIZE']]`

Comment: Wait- do you mean you want to extract the value `2515`, or `2942`? I misunderstood (I thought you were looking for the string `'RFC822.SIZE'`). Anyway, `sizeList[item]["RFC822.SIZE"]` would do it.

Comment: wow, i was using single quotes instead of double...That fixed it! thanks!

Comment: No, single quotes instead of double wouldn't make any difference. Try `sizeList[item]['RFC822.SIZE']`.

Comment: OK, for some very weird reason, single quote wasnt working earlier but now works...OMG, i never really had a question! lol but thanks anyways!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
your_dict = { 1:{'foo':123}}
your_dict[1]['foo']
```

Comment: hello, help? dict = { 1:[{'foo':123}]}
how to get foo value?

Answer (score 0):

```
In [2]: {1: {'RFC822.SIZE': 2515, 'SEQ': 1}, 2: {'RFC822.SIZE': 2942, 'SEQ': 2}}[1]['RFC822.SIZE']
Out[2]: 2515
```

The `{...}[1]` returns the sub-dictionary `{'RFC822.SIZE': 2515, 'SEQ': 1}`, and you can get the value out of this using `['RFC822.SIZE']`.

Answer (score 0):

By 'double dictionary' I suppose you mean *nested* dictionary, right?

Well, when you access a value of the outter dict through a key (let's say, 1), it will return the corresponding inner dict, which values you can access... well, like a dict.

Here's an example:

```
data = {1: {'RFC822.SIZE': 2515, 'SEQ': 1}, 2: {'RFC822.SIZE': 2942, 'SEQ': 2}}

# get the inner dictionary with key 1
key_1 = data[1] # {'RFC822.SIZE': 2515, 'SEQ': 1}

# get RFC822.SIZE
size = key_1['RFC822.SIZE']
```

Knowing this, you can condense all that code by accesing the value directly:

```
size = data[1]['RFC822.SIZE']
```

This is some basic python (you use dicts constantly when coding on python) so I recommend (if you are planning to do serious coding on python) that you read some tuturial, at least the introductory one you can find on the [python's doc page](http://docs.python.org/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You have a nested dictionary, so use nested lookups:

```
for item in sizeList:
    print item, sizeList[item]['RFC822.SIZE']
```

Note the slight difference between this and the usage in your comment: your commment tries to index `item`, whereas this indexes `sizeList[item]`.